# Varying an action with respect to the metric in mathematica

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, computational-physics, variational-calculus, software

I want to Varying an action with respect to the metric to obtain the Einstein equation $G_{\mu\nu}=k^2 T_{\mu\nu}$. Is there any way to do that in Mathematica? Can mathematica do that?

Comment: If you want to do it symbolically, use the xAct package. If you only care about components for a given metric, you can do this by hand.

Comment: Might [mathematica.se] be better suited for this question about Mathematica?

Comment: I you have a code that xAct package was used for variation of action respect to the metric, Could you please share that?